# Need help with adding custom menu content

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to install a Google AdWords snippet on a client website.  It calls for replacing the business phonenumber on the page with something like

```
<span class="number">content</span>
```

The problem is that the phone number is listed in a wordpress menu at the top of the page.  I can't exactly drop the code snippet into the frontend (Appearance->Menus).  How can I integrate this span into the menu?

I got some advice in IRC to check out this these links:
http://pastebin.com/9SJCK1Rh
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/

I'm still not sure how to apply this knowledge, though.  Can someone elaborate on what I need to do to add this custom menu content?  I need to use add_filter in a file somewhere in order to hook a function to wp_nav_menu_items, then use the function to test if it's the right menu and return the content that I want to go into the menu?

Urgent help needed!

Answer (score 0):

For inject `<span>` into menu, you do it using below code:

```
//Setup this code into your current function.php file
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_span_in_menu', 10, 2);
function add_span_in_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary')  {

        $myContent = 'YOURCONTENT'
        $items .=  '<li><span class="number">' . $myContent .  '</span></li>';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

Above snippet will add `<span>` with content to your *WordPress* menu. Hope this help you well!